# Reliably jumping to named anchor on dynamically generated page?

Tags: javascript, css, anchor

I have a web page which is dynamically built by the client.  It generates dozens of list items each with its own named anchor.  The side of the page has a fixed table of contents (TOC) with hyperlinks that point to the named anchors.  This allows the user to click a TOC entry a jump to the item.

The trouble I am encountering is that on the initial page load the page is dynamically generated and so it cannot scroll to the item in the initial hash of the URL using the default behavior of a browser.  Additionally, when the user switches to a different book the page is completely regenerated with new content and a new starting hash.  Same problem: since the hash preexists the content, it doesn't situate itself with the item already in view.

I nearly solved this with JavaScript by awaiting the rendering and then jumping to the hash using `scrollIntoView` method on the appropriate element.

The next problem is that the stylesheet is not fully applied by the time `scrollIntoView` is called and so the final position of the item is unknown.  I see the unstyled item scroll into view, but once styling is applied the positioning is lost.  I put a 1 second `setTimeout` in place to delay the `scrollIntoView` call.  This works but feels fragile.

Are there reliable techniques for jumping to a named anchor when the content comes after the hash is in place?  If I knew when the CSS was done styling content that might help.  Alternately, it might be useful to trigger an event once the height of the page stabilizes (thus signaling the finalization of CSS styling).

Comment: When you say "jump to", do you mean focus? .and, is "hash" an element on the page you're wishing to focus?  and if so, will it always have the same name?

Comment: The content exceeds the viewport and so the item deserving to appear at the top of the viewport (per the hashtag in the URL) needs to be scrolled into view.  The names remain unchanged.

Comment: I edited my answer about focusing, with a link to jquery.scrollTo

Comment: I see no good answers have been given.. To do that you would need to add event listeners for "resize" and "load" events, and I guess another one for the "scroll" event in order to disable your programmatic scroll if the user starts scrolling after the page navigation and before the content got fully loaded.

Comment: @Mario: Did you ever manage to sort this out? I'm in a similar situation and need to solve the same problem.

Comment: @Tomas - that was long ago.  I think I kept the setTimeout.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem, although in my case only the table of contents and named anchors were autogenerated in the onload handler - not the rest of the page content. I solved the initial hash problem by adding the following code to my onload handler after generating the anchors:

```
if (location.hash)
{
    var requested_hash = location.hash.slice(1);
    location.hash = '';
    location.hash = requested_hash;
}
```

I had to set the hash to '' before setting it back to the requested name to make the browser respond. This seemed to work in all the browsers I tried (Opera, Chrome, Edge, IE, FF).

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem. A lot of the page was loaded dynamically, after the document's onload event had fired, and navigating to a given anchor on the page did not work properly. The visitor usually landed at a "random" position on the page and the intended target had been pushed way out of the viewport by dynamically added content that preceded it in the document.

This is how I solved it:

```
(function() {
    var targetElement = document.querySelector(window.location.hash);
    if (targetElement) {
        var stayInPlace = function() {
            targetElement.scrollIntoView();
        };
        var observer = new ResizeObserver(stayInPlace);
        var stopObserving = function() {
            observer.disconnect();
        };
        
        observer.observe(document.querySelector('main'));
        window.addEventListener('wheel', stopObserving, {once: true});
        window.addEventListener('touchstart', stopObserving, {once: true});
    }
})();
```

I'm using the [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) API (available since circa 2018) to detect changes to the size of the `<main>` element. In my case the target and the dynamically loaded elements were all children of the main element. Adjust if needed. On each size change we make sure to scroll the requested target into view.

Whenever the user starts interacting with the page, using either the scroll wheel or touch, we stop observing and forcibly adjusting the scroll position. I was not able to figure out how to detect usage of the scrollbars.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery if you will always know the name of the element you want to set focus to.  You can run this after your page has loaded:

```
$( "#targetElementGoesHere" ).focus();
```

Edit:  To scroll to that, check out https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo

Comment: I believe `focus` only works on input elements.  In any case, I tried that instead of `scrollIntoView` and now it doesn't work even with the delay in place.

Comment: It is for form elements (<input>, <select>, etc.) and links (<a href>), so you can indeed focus your link with it.

Comment: also, check my edit for a link to a scrolling solution for you

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  I have `scrollIntoView` working without the jQuery plugin.  The problem is one of timing.  The item does scroll into view, but the CSS styling is still going and so by the time the styling completes the overall height of the page has been dramatically reduced.  The item then falls out of the viewport.

Comment: Do you have that JavaScript wrapped up in a $(document).ready(function () {}

Comment: Yes, but consider the page is initially blank and so instantly ready.  I then add all elements later.  What I need to solve my problem is to add another `$(document).ready` callback that happens after all new junk I add to the page becomes ready.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107872/discussion-between-mario-and-maulzal).

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer you require was answered by this guy...

[How to wait until a web page is loaded with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463003/how-to-wait-until-a-web-page-is-loaded-with-javascript)

So, something like this...

```
document.onload = function(){ 
    scrollIntoView...
}
```

Comment: I already run all JavaScript in the `onload` event.  The page is entirely blank before this.  Everything is generated via JavaScript.  I do effectively do what you say, scrolling into view once the content is generated.  The problem is that I can see that the CSS styling is not caught up with the content that is added to the page.  Thus, I add the dynamic content, I scroll to the given item, it comes into view, and then a moment later the CSS styling of that content completes causing the item to lose its spot in the viewport.