# Anchor link not working because dynamic content div above has delayed loading

Tags: javascript, html, squarespace

I have a Squarespace website with an anchor link in the footer. It worked fine until we added a div that pulls timetable data from en external website just above the section where the anchor is:

This means on load the page scrolls to the section before the dynamic data has loaded. The dynamic data then loads and moves the anchor section down. This all happens pretty quickly so it looks like the anchor is scrolling to the wrong area on the page.

Is it possible to write javascript to fix this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reliably jumping to named anchor on dynamically generated page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36337703/reliably-jumping-to-named-anchor-on-dynamically-generated-page)

Comment: I added the following code to the head but it did not solve the problem: 

<script type="text/javascript">
document.onload = function(){ 
  if (location.hash)
  {
      var requested_hash = location.hash.slice(1);
      location.hash = '';
      location.hash = requested_hash;
  }
}
</script>

Comment: `document.onload` will fire before your async content is loaded. You need to run that code after the async requests have completed and your dynamic content has loaded too.