# How to get html content of a webpage after some seconds of loading of the target page

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping

I am getting content of a webpage (same domain) with javascript. 
The problem is, that webpage has javascript which do some calculations and then write the result in a div element.

When I retrieve the result, I get the empty div element, because the javascript of the target page still hasn't fully executed.

I need to load the webpage, wait some seconds, and then get the html.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Can you show us some of your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463003/how-to-wait-until-a-web-page-is-loaded-with-javascript

Comment: One possibility could be to trigger the js logic when the dom is ready using DOMContentLoaded. But as Alicia mention please show some code

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this

```
a. $(document).ready(function() {
 // executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready
 alert("document is ready");
});


b. $(window).load(function() {
 // executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images
 alert("window is loaded");
// You can initiate the copy of your Div elements from here.
});
```

You would require option B, as this is the one which will be fired after your entire page is painted with all the content including the images.